# Merging csv file

Tags: java, csv

Please help me in java code. I have 2 CSV FILE
a.csv contains "zip","name","place"
b.csv contains "zip","latitude","longitude"

I need to merge the following columns with the same zip and save in another csv file

output.csv file will be:

"zip","name","place","latitude","longitude"

how am i going to code this? thank you.

I have read this a.csv but i dont know how to merge.

Here's my code in reading my first csv file

public class Merge{public static void main(String[]args ) throws Exception {

```
        String csvFile ="a.csv";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";

try{

    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        // use comma as separator
        String[] cFile = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
    System.out.println("" + cFile[1] + " " + cFile[2] + " ");

    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (br != null) {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

System. out. println("Done");
```

}
   }

Comment: *how am i going to code this?* **ANS:** Using some IDE. We are not here to do code for you!
Show your effort (code), so others will help you by rectifying buy or suggesting correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write the below logic to achieve this. This is just an idea.. go ahead and implement if you get any error in any specific area. You ware welcome to get back with your questions.

1. Read csv 1, populate an array (array 1)
2. Read csv 2, populate another array (array 2)
3. Loop both the array check the zip and merge in 3rd array.. something like below
   for(loop over array 1)
   // get the zip from array1
   for(loop over array 2)
   // get the zip from array2
      if(zip1 == zip2)
         then merge and put the data in another array(array3) and break this loop
4. Write this array3 in a new csv file

Comment: Ok. I see that. You are only reading one file it seems.. what is your logic here ?

Comment: Im trying to read each of the file but I always failed top merge it

Comment: Did you understood the steps that I have mentioned. Did you tried that?